# Table not displaying all of data entered

Tags: javascript, html

so I have this table form that when you hit submit, it should display the information entered. but it only displays the first input entered. I have another table just like this one that works fine, so it must be a small thing that I'm just not seeing.

The table where you enter data:

```
<form id="symptomstable" name="symptomstable">
    <table class="symptoms" width="700px" bgcolor="#BDDBCC" border="3" align="center">
        <th><b>Symptoms</b></th>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="sym1" size="100" id="sym1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="sym2" size="100" id="sym2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="sym3" size="100" id="sym3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="sym4" size="100" id="sym4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="sym5" size="100" id="sym5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="sym6" size="100" id="sym6"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="display1()"/></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Where it outputs to:

```
<table width="900px" align="center" border=1> 
    <tr style="background-color:#BDDBCC;"></br>
    <th align="center"><b>Symptoms Log</b></th>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div id="symarea1"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div id="symyarea2"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div id="symarea3"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div id="symarea4"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div id="symarea5"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div id="symarea6"></div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The javascript:

```
function display1()
    {
    document.getElementById("symarea1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sym1").value; 
    document.getElementById("sym1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("symarea2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sym2").value; 
    document.getElementById("sym2").value = "";
    document.getElementById("symarea3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sym3").value; 
    document.getElementById("sym3").value = "";
    document.getElementById("symarea4").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sym4").value; 
    document.getElementById("sym4").value = "";
    document.getElementById("symarea5").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sym5").value; 
    document.getElementById("sym5").value = "";
    document.getElementById("symarea6").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sym6").value; 
    document.getElementById("sym6").value = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo. If you open up your console after trying to submit the form, you will see that you have an error that says `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. If you look at the line it refers to, you will see that it references `document.getElementById("symarea2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sym2").value;`

In your HTML, the ID of this element is currently `symyarea2`. See: `<td align="center"><div id="symyarea2"></div></td>`.

Check out how to use the console in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)  and [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)